# How to set label width to width of another label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm in the process of writing a GUI for my program (see [here](http://sonrad-ai.tk) for the CLI version) and one of the tasks it does is download an information file from dropbox and displays it to the user. The information it downloads is displayed in a label, and then text input from the user, and output from the program, is displayed in a second label below this. Because I can change the information that it downloads, the width of the top label is variable, and I would like the bottom label to change to be the same width as the top label.

I've used the following codes to try and achieve the result, but nothing seems to work, as the bottom label ends up being either too long or too short:

`conv.configure(width=inf.winfo_width())`  returns 950

`conv.configure(width=inf.cget('width'))`  returns 0

`conv.configure(width=inf['width'])`       returns 0

`conv.configure(width=len(max(open('information.txt'), key=len)))` returns 178 (the length of the longest line)

Here is the GUI layout that I have written:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib

root=Tk()
root.title("ARTIST AI")

inf=Label(root, relief="raised", text="INFORMATION", anchor=N, justify=LEFT)
inf.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

conv=Label(root, height=10, relief="raised", anchor=N, justify=LEFT)
conv.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

ent=Text(root, width=40, height=2)
ent.grid(row=2, column=0)

sub=Button(root, text="Submit", width=10, height=2, relief="raised", command=getinput)
sub.grid(row=2, column=1)

try:        #Downloads the inforrmation from the Info.txt file in my dropbox account to be displayed to the user.
    info=urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6v538utdp8xrmg/Info.txt?dl=1").read().decode('utf-8')
    f=open("information.txt", "w")
    f.write(info)
    f.close()
except urllib.error.URLError:
    try:
        info=open("information.txt", "r").read()
        info=info.replace("\n\n", "\n")
        info="No internet connection available: using last available information"+"\n\n"+info
    except FileNotFoundError: info="No information available. Will download information on next valid connection."
inf.configure(text=info)
conv.configure(width=length_of_inf_label)

mainloop()
```

If anyone knows how to do this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before judging the width of `conv` check if `info` is empty or not. It seems sometimes `info` is empty and that is why you get `0`

Comment: `inf` does contain text, as using `inf.winfo_width()` returns 950, and since the `inf` label has no width specified when it is defined, it must be getting the width number from somewhere. Also, the same numbers are returned if I use `root.update()` before trying to get the width.

Comment: `winfo_width` returns the width in pixels while the unit of the `width` option of the label is characters, that's why it did not worked.

Comment: @j_4321 thanks for the explanation, I hadn't realised that they were in different units. Do you know if there is a way of defining the width of the label in pixels, or does it have to be in characters?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it is possible to set the width in pixels. As you noticed, the width option of the label is 0 when it automatically adapts to its content, so you cannot access the actual width of the label with `cget("width")`. A way to go around your problem would be to set a fixed width for both labels.

Comment: Ive found a way to, sort of, resolve this issue; what im trying to do its display the text in the bottom label as normal, and then have the longest line from the `inf` label underneath the text in the `conv` label, but have it displayed in the background colour. It's probably not the best way to go about this problem, but I've been thinking about it for days now and this is the best I've come up with

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you need this anymore, but this was how I did it. It's a little crude but it works:

```
label1 = Label(root, text="Start")label1.pack({"side": "top"})
label2 = Label(root, text="End")
label2.config(width=len(label1.cget('text'))-1)
label2.pack({"side": "top"})
```